# migrating from oracle to postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT NPO.VIN,(NPO.program_number)::numeric  programme_id,payee_id,account_profile_id,earning_dealer, earning_customer 
from NG_PAYMENT_OUTPUT NPO, 
where NPO.program_number = NIBL.member_id::varchar
  and NRQ.VIN= NPO.VIN
  and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  from NG_FREEZE_PROG_DETAILS NFPD 
                  where NPO.VIN=NFPD.VIN 
                   and NIBL.member_id::varchar = NFPD.FREEZE_PROGRAMME_ID)
  GROUP BY NPO.VIN,NPO.program_number`
```

I tried every possible way and i am getting this error. Can any one help me to resolve this issue

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
> LINE 35:   SELECT NPO.VIN,(NPO.program_number)::numeric  programm...
>            ^
> CONTEXT:  invalid type name "SELECT NPO.VIN VIN"I
> ```

Comment: There is a `,` missing after `(NPO.program_number)::numeric`  and the `,` after `NPO` in the first FROM clause is wrong.

Comment: That statement doesn't throw that error for me. Perhaps your query buffer isn't empty.